# Do I need getVolatile memory access semantics if the value is set with setVolatile?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-barriers, java-memory-model

Now, before some zealot quotes Knuth forgetting what he spent his life on - the question has a mostly educational purpose, as I struggle to understand memory barriers.
Lets assume:

```java
   public class Var<T> {
      private T finalized = null;
      private boolean isFinal = false;
      private T init;

      public Var(T init) { this.init = init; }

      public T getFinal() { return finalized; }
      public T get() { return init; }
      public void set(T val) {
          if (isSet)
             throw new IllegalStateException();
          if (val == null)
             throw new NullPointerException(); //null means finalized is uninitialized.
          init = val;
      }

      public void freeze() {
          isSet = true;
          if (!field.compareAndSet(this, null, init))
              throw new IllegalStateException();
      }

      private static void field = 
          MethodHandles.lookup().findVarHandle(Var.class, "finalized", Object.class);
   }
```

The idea is that a single thread accesses the object in its initial, mutable state, calling `get` and `set`. Afterwards it calls `freeze` and makes the object available
to other threads, which use only `getFinal`. I want to guarantee those threads see
the frozen value. I don't care what happens if in the mutable state multiple threads access it - it is considered not thread safe at that stage.

The questions are:

1. do I need an additional memory barrier in `getFinal`?
2. do I need it if `T` is immutable (contains only final fields)?
3. if I share a reference to a `Var` before calling `freeze`, would a `getVolatile` in `getFinal` change things? Lets assume again `T` is immutable, as otherwise, as I understand, reader threads could see it in an unitialized state.

Comment: I think what it boils down to is, do you have synchronization that ensures that no thread calls `getFinal()` until after `freeze()` returns - formally, that all calls to `freeze()` and other writing functions happen-before all otherwise unsynchronized calls to `getFinal()` and other reading functions?  If so, then you should be good.  If not, then you have a data race.

Comment: Re, "Afterwards it calls freeze and makes the object available to other threads." Why must it be the same object? Would it not be easier to safely publish a new, immutable object—a copy of the original—instead?

Comment: In which way will the preparing thread make the object available to other threads? In a thread safe way, perhaps? Then, this entire complicated setup is unnecessary. But as Solomon Slow said, even when you publish the object in an unsafe way, you can simply publish an immutable object containing a single `final` reference and you’re done. Still no reason for the complicated setup. Think about it, the only methods containing thread safe constructs are the methods supposed to be invoked by a single thread only And why have the `isSet` (or is it `isFinal`?) field when `finalized != null` will do?

Answer (score 3):

Memory barriers are not a [sane mental model](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-barriers-are-sane) for Java. For Java, you need to understand the Java Memory Model.

What you need to ensure is that you should not have a data race; so there should be some happens-before edge between a write and a read (or another write).

In your case, you need to make sure there is a happens-before edge between the construction and configuration of the MyObject-instance, and reading the MyObject-instance. The simplest approach would be:

```
class MyObject{int a,int b;}

class MyObjectContainer{
   volatile MyObject value;
   void set(MyObject value){this.value = value;}
   MyObject get(){return value;}
}

MyObject object = new MyObject();
object.setA(10)
object.setB(20)
myObjectContainer.set(object);
```

And a different thread can then call myObjectContainer.get() safely.

The 'value' needs to be volatile. Otherwise, there would be a data race. This is because volatile generates the happens-before edge (volatile variable rule) required. In combination with the program order rule and the transitivity rule, we get a guaranteed happens-before edge. The above approach is also known under the name 'safe publication'.

The above will only work if the MyObject instance is not modified after it has been written to the myObjectContaier. So it is 'effectively' immutable.

On the X86 a volatile-read is extremely cheap because every load already has acquire-semantics. A volatile-read only restricts compiler optimizations (compiler fence) and is not a CPU memory fence. [The burden on the X86 is on the volatile store](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/on-the-fence-with-dependencies/).

In exceptional cases, the volatile-store can be a performance bottleneck because it effectively stalls the loads till the store buffer has been drained. In those cases, you can play with relaxed memory ordering (so officially they are classified as data races) using either Unsafe or the VarHandle. In your case, an acquire-load and release-store would be the first steps down the rabbit hole. Depending on the situation, even a [StoreStore] fence before an opaque-store and an [LoadLoad] after an opaque-load would be as low as you could possibly get.

Comment: Your answer is of course correct, and has the obvious benefit of being easy to reason about, which outweights in practice any gains from such optimisations in 99.99% of cases. It is however not very helpful as I specifically looked into the minimal overhead possible as an excercise on the API provided by `VarHandle` :/

Comment: What is not helpful? I have given you 2 cheaper versions.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need getVolatile memory access semantics if the value is set with setVolatile?

The short answer is yes.

> do I need an additional memory barrier in getFinal?

You need memory barrier protection, yes.  Just because `field. compareAndSet(...)` has memory protection around the update doesn't mean that another thread will see the update.

If an instance of `Var` is shared between threads such that one thread calls `set()` and another calls `get()` then `init` needs to be `volatile`.  If one thread calls `freeze` and another calls `getFinal()` then `finalized` needs to be `volatile` as well.

> do I need it if T is immutable (contains only final fields)?

The `T` object will not be shared in an inconsistent state if all fields are `final` but that does not protect the `Var` object.  One thread could set the immutable object `T` and then another thread could call `get` and still see the `init` field as `null.

> if I share a reference to a Var before calling freeze, would a getVolatile in getFinal change things?

That doesn't change anything.

Comment: The field.compareAndSet has the same memory ordering semantics as AtomicReference.compareAndSet. See the following link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/VarHandle.html#compareAndSet-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: Thanks @pveentjer.  Obviously not up on my Java9.

Comment: "Just because ... has memory protection around the update doesn't mean that another thread will see the update" - well, but, strictly speaking, nothing can bring that guarantee about, can it? The only things we can guarantee - with various fences - is that the value read is at least as new as some other value read (or written).

Comment: As you mention several theads calling `get`/`set` I'd like to reiterate the use case I had in mind to be on the same ground: 1. A single thread calls `get`/`set` as much as it wants. 2. The same thread calls `freeze()`. 3. The same thread assigns `Var` to some shared variable. 4. Other threads dereference `Var` and call `getFinal`. The fence in freeze() means that `Var.finalized` is set and coherent (for immutable `T`) when we store `var v = myVar`. Can the reader thread calling `v.getFinal` see the value older than `v`? If so, how, when the stores happen in order?

Comment: I mean, if `load(v.finalized)` happens before `load(v)` then, at worst, the thread will see an old value of `v` (and throw a `NPE`), but it cannot see `v.finalized` older than `v` - so `v.finalized` must be not null.

Comment: Folks tracking memory updates use my language all of the time but you are correct that if you are asking about notification of a _specific_ change then that's not possible without a `BlockingQueue` or something @Turin.

Comment: No, that's not correct @Turin.  Regardless that thread1 crossed a memory barrier to update `Var`, thread2 still needs to cross a read memory barrier afterwards to be guaranteed proper publishing of the update.  Thread2 already had the reference to `Var` before `thread2` called freeze and that memory could be out of date.